# Are updates released all at once or ad hoc?

Tags: updates, package-management

Does Ubuntu have a fixed package update cycle like Microsofts patch Tuesday? Or are packages just updated and released ad hoc.  I've checked around and can't find an answer which makes me think they are released as and when they are needed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are released as and when they are needed.

Users will see security updates immediately.  But otherwise, the Software Updater will (by default) only notify users once a week.

There is additionally some experimental support for phasing updates out to a higher and higher percentage of users over time.  This isn't widely used yet, to my knowledge.  But it's built into the infrastructure.

Comment: I believe that Software Updater check once a day, is not?

Comment: Software Updater checks once a day, but will not show updates immediately unless there is a security update.  But you can configure it always notify you about even normal updates by going to the Updates tab of the "Software & Updates" preference app.

Comment: Landscape can also be used to manage the update cycle within a separate security perimeter (e.g. a company's firewall) from a local mirror, with managed, staged or automated update processes.